# MVC: Ajax POST removes backslash

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently trying to use ajax to post a string to a controller action, however, for some reason the backslash in my string is removed when the my controller action receives the data.

#### view.cshtml

This is what I pass from my Razor view to JS

```
// Model.BookTitle = "Peter Rabbit \1234"
var book = {
    title: '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.BookTitle)',
}
```

#### JavaScript

```
function saveBookTitle(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/savebooktitle',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { bookTitle: book.title },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('saved');
        }
    })
}
```

#### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveBookTitle(string bookTitle)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The data I receive at the `SaveBookTitle` action is "Peter Rabbit 1234". Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Set it as string literal: `Model.BookTitle = @"Peter Rabbit \1234"`. The difference is the `@` character before the first quote.

Comment: How would I sort this issue out if I can't set the string as a literal?

Comment: If you write `\n` without using `@""` it will render a new line and not two characters backslash and n.

Comment: You can use a string literal `@"\1 \1 \1"` or escape all your backslashes `"\\1 \\1 \\1"`.

Comment: Assigning `Model.BookTitle = "Peter Rabbit \1234"` in controller action method may produce `Unrecognized escape sequence` error. If you can't use string literals, use escape sequence for backslash (`"\\"`).